# Dynamic filter with Firebase API not working

Tags: angularjs, api, firebase, filtering, browserify

I am using and [angular-firebase boilerplate](https://github.com/jakemmarsh/angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate) with node and to create a blog. I want the global search input to filter the items dynamically based on which section of the website you are in. The search filter is inside the index.html page:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='searchFilter' placeholder='Search...'>
```

So for example, to create a "Blog" page and make it display results from the global search filter, I use `stateProvider` to pull the `blog.html` template and generate a controller for this page:

```
  .state('Blog', {
    url: '/blog',
    controller: 'BlogCtrl as blg',
    templateUrl: 'blog.html',
    title: 'Blog'
  })
```

Within the blog.html, I have an ng-repeat directive with the following instruction:

```
  <div ng-repeat='post in blg.myPosts | filter:searchFilter'>
    <pre>{{ myPosts| json }}</pre>
  </div>
```

I created a `services.js` with instructions to pull my dummy data as a factory across multiple controllers returning a firebase Array:

```
servicesModule.factory('dataService', function($firebaseArray) {
  return $firebaseArray(new Firebase('https://glowing-torch-8451.firebaseio.com/Posts/'));
});
```

Then for the Blog controller I connect my `dataService` factory to display the results from the Api:

```
controllersModule.controller('BlogCtrl', function($firebaseArray, dataService) {
  blg.title = 'The Blog';
  blg.myPosts = dataService;
})
```

The whole thing is then build using a gulp and browserify:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {

  return buildScript('main.js');

});
```

Because of the way this boilerplate is built, I am unable to run a simple angular filter on the client side to display the results within each page (especially as firebase does not return the results as an array but as an object) and the whole thing fails with a `ReferenceError: blg is not defined` error.

I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xSzmtnaJwyxancmQARh3?p=preview) to show as an example but it is very difficult to separate the code parts therefore it is more of an example to illustrate what I am doing rather than a prototype.

Am I overcomplicating or using the search filter in the wrong manner?

Thanks

Comment: $firebaseArray does return an array and can be filtered. [Here's a plunker demonstrating that](http://plnkr.co/edit/qQqtoF91XNTEO7pJkLQ5?p=preview). Also, you need to have `var blg = this` in your controller if you're using controllerAs.

Comment: This has worked Anid. I don't understand why it was not working before, what did you change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `controllerAs` syntax, you need to bind your variables to `this` within the controller. It seems you left out that one line of code, assigning `blg`.

```
controllersModule.controller('BlogCtrl', function($firebaseArray, dataService) {
  var blg = this;
  blg.title = 'The Blog';
  blg.myPosts = dataService;
})
```

Also, inside your `ng-repeat`, you refer to `myPosts`. This needs to be a reference to `post`, since that's what you called each element in the `ng-repeat`.

```
<pre>{{ post | json }}</pre>
```